# Error on paramiko SSH on executing remoting commands. "The handle is invalid"

Tags: c#, python, ssh, exe, paramiko

I have written a method inside a class ( for SSH connection using paramiko ) in Python to execute a remote exe on a windows server.
The method is:

```
    '''
Created on Feb 25, 2014

    '''


"""Friendly Python SSH interface."""

import os
import paramiko
from hashlib import md5
import stat
import time
import shutil
import glob

class SSHConnection(object):

    """Connects and logs into the specified hostname.

     ALL functions return a tuple

     e.g.,
     return (False,{'msg'}:'RELEVANT MESSAGE')

     So while calling any of these methods, call like:
     e.g.,

     result, reply = get('./Raiden/example.txt','C:/tmp/example.txt')

     And check/print error if successfully executed or not, using:

     if not result:
        print(reply['msg'])

     """


    def __init__(self):

        pass


    def establish_conn(self, host,username="xxxx",password="xxxx",port=xx):

        self._sftp_live = False
        self._sftp = None

        # Begin the SSH transport.
        print ("Establishing an SSH Connection to : " +host );

        try:
            self._transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
            self._transport_live = True

        except Exception as e:
            print ('SSH error: ' + str(e))
            return False, {'msg':'SSH error: ' + str(e)}

        # Authenticate the transport.

        try:
            if password:
                msg = self._transport.connect(username=username, password=password)

        except Exception as e:
            print ('SSH error: '+str(e))
            return False, {'msg':'SSH error: ' + str(e)}

        return True, {'msg': 'Connection established'}


    def _sftp_connect(self):

        """Establish the SFTP connection."""

        if not self._sftp_live:
            self._sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(self._transport)
            self._sftp_live = True


    def get(self, remotepath, localpath=None):

        """Copies a file from the remote host to the local host."""

        if not localpath:

            if not os.path.isdir("C:/tmp"):
                os.mkdir("C/tmp")
            localpath = "C:/tmp/" + (os.path.split(remotepath)[-1].split('.')[0]  + \
                                     "-" + time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + '.' + os.path.split(remotepath)[-1].split('.')[1])
            print ("File will be downloaded to localpath: " +localpath)

        if not os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(localpath)):
             print ("Local directory path does not exists! Enter a valid directory path or create the path manually. ")
             return False, {'msg': 'Localpath not present! '}

        else:

            try:

                self._sftp_connect()
                self._sftp.get(remotepath, localpath)

            except Exception as e:

                print('File to be downloaded not available at remote box')
                return False,{'msg':str(e)}


        return True, {'msg':'File downloaded successfully !'}


    def put(self, localpath, remotepath=None):

        """Copies a file from the local host to the remote host."""

        self._sftp_connect()
        self._sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)


    def execute(self, command, timeOut=100):

        """Execute the given commands on a remote machine."""

        try:
            channel = self._transport.open_session()

            x = channel.get_pty()

            channel.timeout = timeOut
            channel.exec_command('cmd /c' + command)
            output = channel.makefile('rb', -1).readlines()
            print (str(output) + " " + str(command))

            return True, {'msg': 'Command succesfully executed. '}

        except Exception as e:
            return False, {'msg': 'Command could not be executed on the remote server. ' + str(e)}


    def checkIsFileRemote(self, path=None):

        """ Checks whether a file is present in remote host or not"""

        if not path:
            return False, {'msg': 'File path not provided checking'}

        try:
            self._sftp_connect()
            x = self._sftp.stat(path)

        except Exception as e:
            return False, {'msg': 'Path could not be stat: ' + str(e)}

        if not stat.S_ISREG(x.st_mode):
            return False, {'msg': 'Not a file'}

        return True, {'msg': 'Path is a file'}


    def checkIsDirectoryRemote(self, path=None):

        """ Checks whether a directory is present in remote host or not"""

        if not path:
            return False, {'msg': 'Directory path not provided checking'}

        try:
            self._sftp_connect()
            x = self._sftp.stat(path)

            if x.__str__()[0] == 'd':
                return True, {'msg': 'Path is a directory.'}

        except Exception as e:

            errStr = 'Path could not be stat: ' + str(e)
            return False, {'msg': errStr}

        if stat.S_ISREG(x.st_mode):
            return False, {'msg': 'Its a file not a directory !!'}


    def close(self):

        """Closes the connection and cleans up."""

        try:
            # Close SFTP Connection.
            if self._sftp_live:
                self._sftp.close()
                self._sftp_live = False
            # Close the SSH Transport.
            if self._transport_live:
                self._transport.close()
                self._transport_live = False
        except Exception as e:
            return False, {'msg': 'Could not close the SSH connection. ' + str(e)}
        return True, {'msg': 'SSH connection closed successfully'}


if __name__ == '__main__':

    sshObj = SSHConnection()
    result, reply = sshObj.establish_conn('my-server-box')
    reply=sshObj.execute('E:\\abc1.exe /md5 0808197FB92CEF2939EB249E6E79FB6E /outdir E:\\one') #This is working fine
    reply=sshObj.execute('E:\\abc2.exe -collection=E:\\one') # This gives the reply : 'The handle is invalid.'
```

So there is no problem with my method. It is working fine. 
The error might be related to how the `abc2.exe` is written.

Any suggestions if anyone has encountered this before. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be easier to debug if you also include the _actual_ code that calls the two execute() methods (see http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: @user1656850 ...thanks for the comment. I have entered the complete code for your reference. please see if you can help here.

Comment: since I assume you do not have the source of E:\\abc2.exe, you may want to see what happens if you execute E:\\abc1.exe on its own, or after E:\\abc2.exe, or execute E:\\abc2.exe on its own.